# time series with 365.25 frequency not running any forecast package functions in updated R versions

Tags: r

I recently was using *3.4.2* version of R, and have just upgraded to *3.4.3*. Also to *3.4.4* then *3.4.5*

The daily time series data with frequency of 365.25 is not running for the updated versions, when `auto.arima` or `tso` (from "tsoutliers") is run on the ts dataset.

But runs fine with frequency of 365 days or 7 or 52...whatever non- decimal frequency is required.

But throws an error when `auto.arima` or tso run for 365.25 frequency like:

```
Error in x[, (1 + cs[i]):cs[i + 1]] <- xx : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

How can I reslove this issue?